# How to understand 'flatter to deceive'?

Tags: meaning, expressions

How should you understand the expression: "flatter to deceive"?

The Oxford Dictionaries defines [flatter to deceive](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/flatter-to-deceive) as:

> Appear promising but ultimately disappoint.

Which is all nice and dandy. But I fail to understand the wordplay, nor how "flatter" is mechanically related to "deceive" in this expression.

For a real-life [example of usage](http://thejudge13.com/2014/04/22/94779/#Ron%20Dennis%20hauling%20Mclaren%20back%20into%20line%20-%20slowly):

> The podium that Kevin Magnussen scored on his debut was ultimately a case of ‘flattering to deceive.’

[Kevin Magnussen's car scored a good result in his first race, but bad to worse results thereafter. The car flattered in the beginning, and deceived later on.]

Comment: Do you have an example of this expression in context? I haven't seen it used before and the definition isn't very illuminating.

Comment: It's quite literal, "mechanical" in fact. See usage examples to get an idea.

Comment: @Kris Context should really be in the question, and telling me to Google it is not constructive.

Comment: After *To April* (Henry Kirke White)
"So, to us sojourners in life's low vale,
The smiles of fortune flatter to deceive,
While still the Fates the web of misery weave."

Comment: @BraddSzonye "Psalm 5 warns against deception, especially through flattery. &hellip; The worst deception done to anyone is through flattery. People flatter to deceive you and have ulterior motives." http://books.google.co.in/books?id=iNWSjxy0lDYC&pg=PA102

Comment: @BraddSzonye What *can* be googled is a no ball on ELU.

Comment: @Kris That second example does not appear to be the same expression in the question, in form or meaning.

Comment: Tell us what you think 'flatter' means in the context of your question? I hope this doesn't sound too rude or presumptuous but do you think it means 'make flat, like a floor' the same way 'flatten' would. ?

Comment: I added the real-life example that prompted my question.

Comment: @Kris Could you please attempt to explain the mechanics? My mind isn't managing the necessary gymnastics to understand it.

Comment: Landroni: the expression when translated would work on any language (assuming they have words like 'to flatter' and 'to mislead'

Comment: @Mitch Not quite. Take French: should it be "flatter pour décevoir" or "flatter à décevoir"? And for the record, no one in France uses such an expression. I suspect that it all hinges on the "to" bit, and it's idiomatic use in English. I'm not sure what's the proper translation in other languages.

Comment: @landroni: I don't know what would be most natural in French. But it is the general concepts that matter, not the expression. Flattery, appealing to someone's pride (or however one might explain or translate) can be used to mislead or deceive someone else by taking advantage of that pride. 'to' can be explicated by 'in order to' or 'to bring about'.

Answer (score 4):

Since you added the context it is easier to describe the meaning.

From the performance in the first GP Magnussen's car (and Kevin himself) looked as if they were good enough to be competitive with Mercedes and Ferrari. In the races since then it is clear that neither the car nor Magnussen are as quick as the front runners.

One of the definitions of **flatter** is **give an unrealistically favourable impression of**.

That leaves us with the **deceive** part. If the performance in the first race made you think that Magnussen and his car were competitive then by now you'd know that they are not, you had been deceived into think he was competitive.

This example may not be a particularly good one, **flatter to deceive** is usually intentional, in Magnussen's case I don't think they (McLaren) intentionally put in a spectacular performance in order to attract sponsorship or something and then allowed themselves to slip back down the order over the next few races.

Edited to add a **very** literal **flatter to deceive** example

A very young woman dates a very old billionaire, she says she loves him because he is the nicest, sweetest, most caring man she's ever met (she flatters him). He believes this, they get married, she quickly files for divorce and gets half his money. (she has deceived him)

Comment: So, to paraphrase, it is to "intentionally flatter in order to deceive someone". Correct?

Comment: @landroni Yes, usually a little less obviously than the very literal version above, and in the case of McLaren I don't think it was intentional (by McLaren) but maybe the journalists who ran with **Magnussen will challenge Vettel for the Championship** may have been keen to get more readers.

Comment: Then this means that half of the times that I encounter this expression it is improperly used (as in the example above, as McLaren didn't intentionally deceive all to look good at first race but slump afterwards), as it lacks the element of intent (as you point out in your answer). Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @landroni Yes, it's not always the case that it is intentional, in the McLaren case I suspect they knew they got lucky; good track for them (Button was third) and a number of normally top drivers out of the race effectively. The result flattered them but anyone who may have bet money on them on the next few races based on that performance will feel deceived. It's not always cut & dried that the flattery and deception is planned.

Comment: OK, then I gather that another literal version would be: "getting flattered somehow and consequently deceive someone". :)

Comment: @landroni Not really, the flattered party is not the one that does the deceiving, they are the one that will be deceived. That's why the McLaren case isn't a very good example of it. When talking about people, it is almost always the flatterer that is planning the deception.

Comment: Given the poetic example that Kris showed in comments, I suspect that this expression is more often used figuratively, that it's about glittery things not actually being gold.

Comment: @BraddSzonye It's along the same lines, _all that glitters/glisters is not gold_ is more often used about objects (that you intend buying) a bit like _if it's too good to be true then.._ but _flatters to deceive_ is usually used when talking about people and the deceiver getting people to drop their guard by making them think they are special in order to make them easier to dupe. A bit of _pride comes before a fall_.

Comment: I'm not convinced that *flatter to deceive* is usually used intentionally, but it may have started out that way. One of the first 20th-century uses I can find of it in Google books is from the *Economist* in 1984: *The doubters say BAe's accounts flatter to deceive, with profits looking better because so much expenditure has been capitalised.*

Comment: I have always heard 'flatter to deceive' used in an unintentional situation - usually about underperforming sports teams. I have *never* heard it used when the flatterer was performing an intentional act. Not once.

Answer (score 1):

It is a term often used in football.  A young player bursts onto the scene and appears to be very good.  Everyone talks about how he will be the next Pele or Messi, but as the season wears on, it becomes apparent that he is not as good as originally thought.  Often football fans will say that he "flattered to deceive."

In this context, clearly the young player never really "flattered" anyone.  Nor was there ever intent to deliberately "deceive."  So, the saying does not apply in a literal sense.  Over the years, the phrase has simply taken on a new, non-literal meaning.  This is common in the English language.

Answer (score 1):

Someone flatters you, thus giving you promises, but ends up deceiving you, thus disappointing you. They flattered you, only to deceive you once you bought into the flattery.

Answer (score 1):

Much of english is derived from French, and it is to the French verb decevoir we must look here.  It is what students of french call a "faux-ami" or false friend.  Decevoir doesn't mean deceive but disappoint. To flatter means to make someone pleased - close to the more normal meaning, ie to praise.  Putting them together you get the idea of initially making someone pleased, only the more to disappoint afterwards.

Comment: Ah, now this makes sense: "to flatter at first, only to disappoint later on". Curious to know that there is a French connection...

Answer (score 0):

flattered,  simply that,  is  used  in horse racing  jargon -form,  to indicate  that  a  horse  briefly appeared  to be  going well but  ultimately disappointed.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. It's a good idea to add further detail and some references on the answers you provide.

Answer (score 0):

With a pencil whose core is broken throughout, sharpening will always flatter to deceive. Every time a new point is created, it will look the part, but immediately fail in use, requiring sharpening all over again.